# If A and B are the same after X seconds, reduce A

Tags: javascript, logic, setinterval

I'm presently trying to learn JavaScript by creating an incremental game.

One of my variables (called 'renown') should always be going up if the player is interacting or has "hired" recruits. However, if they're idle and recruits have "died", I would like renown to decrease slowly and the rate of decrease to increase over time until renown is 0.

I think I've figured out the renown decrease multiplier, but the part I'm struggling with is the "idle" state.

This is the code I presently have:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    var lastrenown = renown;
    document.getElementById("lastrenown").innerHTML = lastrenown;
}, 3000);

function renowndeccalc() {
    if (renown != 0) {
        if (renown == lastrenown) {
            renown = renown - (100 * idlerenownmultiplier);
            document.getElementById("renown").innerHTML = renown;
            idlerenownmultiplier++
        }
    }
}

setInterval(renowndeccalc, 5000);
```

The intention here being that every 3 seconds 'lastrenown' is updated to match renown. If the player or recruits are active, lastrenown should never equal renown.

If the player or recruits aren't active, lastrenown should equal renown, at which point every 5 seconds renown decreases by 100 * the multiplier.

What's actually happening is renown doesn't change at all. If I remove the 0 check so the function is as follows:

```
function renowndeccalc() {
        if (renown == lastrenown) {
            renown = renown - (100 * idlerenownmultiplier);
            document.getElementById("renown").innerHTML = renown;
            idlerenownmultiplier++
        }
}
```

Renown will go down by 100 after 5 seconds and then not repeat.

My understanding is that setInterval should cause the function to repeat as often as you determine, but *something* in the logic is causing my script to not work as intended.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the end: I should have used one function and calculated everything within, like so:

```
function renowndeccalc() {
    if (renown != 0) {
        if (renown <= 0) {
            renown = 0;
            lastrenown = 0;
            document.getElementById("renown").innerHTML = renown;
            document.getElementById("lastrenown").innerHTML = lastrenown;
            idlerenownmultiplier = 1;
        }
        else if (renown > lastrenown) {
            lastrenown = renown;
            document.getElementById("lastrenown").innerHTML = lastrenown;
        }
        else if (renown == lastrenown) {
            var calc = 100 * idlerenownmultiplier;
            if (calc > renown) {
                renown = 0;
                lastrenown = 0;
                document.getElementById("renown").innerHTML = renown;
                document.getElementById("lastrenown").innerHTML = lastrenown;
                idlerenownmultiplier = 1;
            }
            else {
                renown = renown - calc;
                lastrenown = renown;
                document.getElementById("lastrenown").innerHTML = lastrenown;
                document.getElementById("renown").innerHTML = renown;
                idlerenownmultiplier++
            }
        }
    }
}

setInterval(renowndeccalc, 5000);
```